# can't disable CSRF component or get csrf token successfully checked from android POST

Tags: android, cakephp-3.0

Since CakePHP 3.0.4 release, I cannot access anymore to my webservices from my Android application!

I explored in CsrfComponent.php(), in the method _validateToken() and it finds an empty token!

Waiting to understand what to do on Android side, I tried to use the following deactivation explained in the doc:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem remains, anyway I saw that in a get request where I return the token, the csrf token is not present anymore. So the call above seems to do something but why it doesn't prevent the token checking??

If I don't load the CSRF component everything goes well!

So I'm interesting by any idea which could help me to still enable to CSRF component for all accesses with a solution to momentary disabling it for some requests or, better, a way to pass CSRF token and CSRF header with android API 22 as all existing examples run with deprecated functions...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is an all or nothing thing, if the object would really be unsubscribed, then you wouldn't get any CSRF validation checks anymore. So for starters I'd suggest to add some debug output in the components `startup()` method to check whether it's really not being invoked anymore.

Comment: @ndm In fact the basic thing is that I don't know what to do since 3.0.4 in order to not get the 'Invalid CSRF token' error message when I perform POST requests from Android. That perfectly worked before. Do I have to first ask for a token to cake?

Comment: Well, if you want to use the CSRF protection feature, then yes, you'll ofcourse have to obtain a token first (via a GET request), if it worked before without, ie the CSRF component being enabled, but no error being thrown when POSTing without token, then that was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have disabled it from your **Controllers** and also **config > routes.php**

Comment below lines of code from routes.php file:

```
$routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
  'httpOnly' => true
]));

$routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
```